# Should I Use The IDisposable Dispose Pattern Only For A Disposable Dependency?

Tags: c#, idisposable

In the scenario where I'm using a disposable dependency in my type should I just avoid using the IDisposable dispose pattern to avoid the running of the finalizer which will be in effect a useless waste?
Example:

```
class SomeType : IDisposable
{
    private SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(5);
    public bool IsDisposed{get;private set;}

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                semaphore.Dispose();
            }
            IsDisposed= true;
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(disposing: true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    ~SomeType()=>Dispose(false);
}
```

Should I just avoid the Dispose Pattern All together and just implement the single Dispose method in this scenario?

Comment: If you using `SemaphoreSlim` as a lingering instance member (which does need to be disposed) then its advisable to use the dispose pattern. However, there is no need for you to have a Finalizer in this class (or in just about any situation). Since you are removing your finalizer (\*nod\*) there is also no need for `SuppressFinalize`

Comment: How Come the SemaphoreSlim instance does not need to be disposed?

Comment: @AQPBXcI91 What makes you say that it doesn't?

Comment: Oh sorry my bad I misread 00110001's comment

Comment: In general you only need the full dispose pattern (with the finalizer cleanup) if you have unmanaged resources. SemaphoreSlim is a managed class, so there is no need for the full pattern.